# jquery/javascripts not loading in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am having a very weird problem that just came up and my guess it's that it may be easy to solve, I just can't seem to figure out.

in my layout/application.html.haml, I have the following:

= javascript_include_tag :all

Rather than RoR translating this to a lot of script-loading lines, it does the following:

```
<script src="/beta/assets/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

similarly, with defaults I get:

```
<script src="/beta/assets/defaults.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What should I look for? or what I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you're using the asset pipeline you should add

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

and in your `application.js` add your required js files

Comment: Hi @Andrei S,
Thanks for the reply, I do have a line like that and my application.js has the following:


`//= require jquery`
`//= require jquery-ui`
`//= require jquery_ujs`
`//= require announcements`
`//= require twitter/bootstrap`
`//`
`//= require_tree .`


Which includes all of the files I want to load, but I don't see them been loaded in my html source. Ultimately my tabs from bootstrap don't work anymore, but they used to work fine before :s

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The :all option in Rails 3.1 is deprecated.

Instead, you should do something like:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

And in your `application.js` add the js file you want to load. `require_tree .` will add all the js file in the same directory with `application.js`.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Hi @xdazz,
Now I get it...I did upgrade to 3.2 and it broke from there. However, I did try to do this method and it didn't work. 


most likely, the problem lies somewhere else.